# Cannot alter the role and grant permission to yourself in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a user assigned with the Server Role which is not sysadmin. Although the user has the ability to create a database, the user cannot create tables within it. In my attempt to modify the user's Role and grant additional permissions, such as the ability to create or control tables, I encountered an error stating, "Cannot alter the role 'db_ddladmin', because it does not exist or you do not have permission." and "Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself." respectively. The application dynamically generates the database and tables, making it impractical to manually grant permissions in SSMS. I utilized the following scripts

```
ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER newuser

GRANT CREATE TABLE TO newuser
```

When I try to run the following it does not work either.

```
CREATE DATABASE TEST2
GO
USE TEST2
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_ddladmin', 'newuser';
CREATE TABLE DBO.SOMETABLE (ID INT)
GO
```

Comment: If a `LOGIN` has permissions to `CREATE` a `DATABASE` then when they `CREATE` it the `USER` `dbo` will automatically be mapped to their `LOGIN`, which has the `db_owner` privileges. There will be no `USER` `newuser`.

Comment: "they are unable to create tables within it" doesn't make sense. The creator of a database is automatically the owner by default

Comment: I have been [unable to reproduce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXfaM.png) the problem; creating the database as a `LOGIN` with the `dbcreator` role and then impersonating the `LOGIN` in the database it created provided no permission errors.

Comment: @ThomA Check my updates.

Comment: @Charlieface Check my updates.

Comment: Your update doesn't change anything; what you state simply isn't how SQL Server works. When a `LOGIN` `CREATE`s a database they are automatically the *owner* of that database and so have full `db_owner` rules.

Comment: Perhaps you have some kind of explicit `DENY` against the user in the `model` database? Remember, when a database is created, it *copies* the `model`. A `DENY` will still work against a `db_owner`; only a `sysadmin` is "immune" to `DENY` permissions.

Comment: Is `newuser` the actual user executing these commands? Then no this isn't going to work: the user *already* has those permissions and these commands are unnecessary

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, newuser is executing these commands.

Comment: So why do you need to give it permissions on the database? It's the database owner anyway, so it's pointless. Just remove it all. "the user cannot create tables within it" you would need to demonstrate why that is the case if they are the database owner. Is there a `DENY` somewhere? Are you `REVOKING` their permissions?

Comment: @Charlieface Because I could not create tables after I had created database from newuser.

Comment: Like @ThomA said already, we cannot reproduce this behavior so you would need to show what exact commands you are running when creating the database and tables. Have you actually checked who the owner of the database is?

Comment: As a side note, `sp_addrolemember` is deprecated; you shouldn't be using it any more.

Comment: If you want you are free to use the [code](https://pastebin.com/Q7rbahxS) I used to demonstrate a [no-repro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXfaM.png) earlier and alter it to replicate the behaviour you're getting. Note that this assume the initial `LOGIN` is a `sysadmin` (as it `CREATE`s a `LOGIN` and impersonates it).

Comment: @ThomA If you create a user first and then execute the script from SSMS by opening a window from the user, it gives error.

Comment: I've asked for many times for a [mre], I'm not entertaining this question without one, @xyz .

Answer (score -3):

The 'db_ddladmin' is not a default Server Role that SQL Server Provides (unless somebody created a new custom role).

In Order to modify / create / assign roles to a Login in SQL Server, you yourself need to login first with ***SysAdmin*** role. This role has all the rights in SQL Server and ability to Grant and Revoke Permissions.

Also in SQL Server, there are two types of users. Based on these concepts, you can create permissions depending on your need.

1. Logins (using this you login to SQL server and these reside at server level)
2. Users (Users are associated with logins and reside under Database)

Do refer below two screenshots shared at last.

Please refer below article from Microsoft to understand roles.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver16

Please refer below article to Understand Users.

https://www.educba.com/sql-users/

[image]

[image]

Comment: *"The 'db_ddladmin' is not a default Server Role that SQL Server Provides (unless somebody created a new custom role)."* It's a *database* role, and it *is* a built in one (and has been there since at least SQL Server 2005 IIRC). The OP isn't trying to alter a server role either as they use `ALTER ROLE`. To alter a server role it's `ALTER SERVER ROLE`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver16#fixed-database-roles